# It looks like the config file at 'bert-base-uncased' is not a valid JSON file?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Working fine for months, then I interrupted a `"bert-large-cased"` download and the following code returns the error in the title:

```
from transformers import BertModel
BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

I've tried:

1. deleting .cache/transformers/...
2. pip uninstall/reinstall transformers
3. conda remove/install transformers
4. completely reinstalling anaconda and my environment from scratch

Comment: I'm having the same error. Wondering if you were able to resolve this? @cyberfunk

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).